# My customized media player won't work with GeForce RTX

Tags: c, windows, media-player, video-card, rtx

I've developed a customized media player, using ffmpeg decoders, in C, and display the video with either Direct3D or GDI, all work fine and well.

But some of my customers have reported me that using GeForce RTX card, the video image won't show.

Personally I don't own a RTX card so can't debug.

Is there a rule for developing such an app to be compatible with RTX?

Is there a way to check such a compatibility?

tnks.

Comment: There is unlikely to be a set of rules you could blindly follow. You have to figure out what the actual problem is. Work with the affected customers, give them a debug build, collect logs, repeat until solved...